# add class to table row when glyhicon is clicked

Tags: jquery, css, addclass, glyphicons

Ok so here it is I have no clue where to go next or how this works so any help will be awsome I want know how to add a class "success" to a table row when A glyphicon is cliked here's my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/R3nierjvr/poz9dwhg/)

```
<tbody>
                <tr class="quest <!-- success class must added here -->">
                    <td class="questNo"><strong>1</strong>
                    </td>
                    <td class="questType">Main Scenario</td>
                    <td class="questLvl">1</td>
                    <td class="questName"><a href="#">Close to Home</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="questGiver">Giver 1</td>
                    <td class="questLocation">Area A X: 11 Y: 13</td>
                    <td class="questClass">Any Class</td>
                    <td class="questCompletion" title="Mark Quest as Done"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: sry i do not realy know much jquery if you look at my fiddle you will se my table what i need to do is add succes to table row when I click the glyphicon in the last colum so I know I have to add a onlick function but dont know how sry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an event listener, like this

```
$("body").on("click",".questCompletion > .glyphicon-ok", function(){
    $(this).parents("tr").addClass("glyphicon-clicked");
    $(this).parents("td").removeClass("questCompletion"); // removes the cell class
    $(this).remove(); // removes itself
});
```

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davcs86/x7pfa0gr/2/)

Comment: cool stuff this worked I just changed the class : to success....but how do i remove it now as when it's clicked i can remove it

Comment: sry still messing with it here is my updated fiddle [link]https://jsfiddle.net/R3nierjvr/poz9dwhg/

Comment: still can not get it to remove the .success class after it's added...sry im a bit of a noob :)